# Read Text from SKLabelNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I attempt to read text form a `SKLabelNode`. However i always get "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". But there can't be a nil value since I initialized the Node and added Text to it. The Code is bellow. Does anyone know why?

```
        powerStar = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ChalkboardSE-Bold")
    powerStar.fontSize = 30
    powerStar.fontColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
    powerStar.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(self.OFFSET + self.COUNTOFFSET + (self.HORIZONTALSPACE * self.activePowers)), y: self.vertivalAlignment)
    powerStar.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Left
    powerStar.text = String(format: ": %d", 10)
    self.addChild(powerStar)
```

...

```
    func update(model:Model){
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector:   Selector("updateAllHuds"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

...

```
else if self.starActive{
        _ = Int(self.powerStar.text!)
    }
```

Comment: where is the first code block placed? The timer probably fires before the first code is executed. why are you using a `SKLabelNode?` if you then simply force unwrap it - that does not make any sense. Either make it `SKLabelNode!` or do not force unwrap but conditionally unwrap.

Comment: @luk2302 the OP is force unwrapping `text` not the `SKLabelNode`. OP, you should an `SKAction` instead of an `NSTimer` in sprite kit games.